# Loading images from a html string into UITextView or UIWebView

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a html string which looks like

```
<h1>Header</h1><h2>Subheader</h2><p>Some <em>text</em></p><img src=\"http://dreamatico.com/data_images/flowers/flowers-4.jpg\" width=70 height=100 />
```

I want to load the text of this html and also the images either into a `UITextView` or `UIWebView`. How would I do that?

Comment: you have to parse HTML string in iOS. There are libraries available on GIT. For reference http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios

if you using WebView, then just load html file in webview by crearting a NSURLrequest.

Comment: You could but if you know it will be exactly this string you can also manually remove the first 14 characters and the last 15 or so and make an image of the remainder

Comment: But I should indeed advise to use html parsing because that works a lot better, if you can't figure out how to do that in swift I will show you how I did it.

Comment: Hello Eric... can you please show me how to parse html in swift?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't load images into a text view. But UIWebView is pretty easy, assuming you have a reference to one in the storyboard, or have alloc-init'd one, you can simply do

```
UIWebView * webView;
[webView loadHTMLString: @"<html><b>My HTML!</b></html>" baseURL: nil];
```

Comment: Or `webView.loadHTMLString("<html><b>My HTML!</b></html>", baseURL: nil)` for the Swift inclined.

Comment: No problem! If the solution helped, please consider accepting the answer :)